# Sorry! Fire Token Bumping Rule

Tags: sorry

In Sorry! if I have the fire token, and I advance to the next corner fire slot before drawing my card, do you bump somebody else back to start who is on the fire slot before drawing the card?  My thought is no, but I wanted to get another opinion.  My wife and I argued for about an hour on this.  We need a mediator...

Comment: that doesn't sound like the *Sorry!* I grew up with :)

Comment: Sorry! has changed a bit. We just bought it to play with our 5 year old. My thought would be to resolve any actions that accompany the fire slot first, then draw the card. If I remember right, the instructions aren't very forthcoming with the "steps" of your "turn"

Answer (score 1):

I would say yes. The rules state that two pawns can never occupy the same space. Since it is your turn and you advance your pawn with the fire token to the corner, it would make sense to return the opposing player's pawn to start. The only time you wouldn't be able to do this would be if:

> 1. There is a pawn with the ice token on the fire corner
> 2. One of your pawns is on the fire corner.

Both of these scenarios would involve you not moving your pawn with the fire token to the corner. Otherwise, *Sorry!* is the name of the game.

The only reason I could see this having an effect would be if you have no other pawns on the board and the card you draw after sending the opposing pawn home is a 4.